# <fieldset> has no border

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use a `<fieldset>` to group some controls.  No matter what I do I can't get the border to display.  My understanding is it should display by default.  In the `<style>` I've tried setting `border-width:1px` which does nothing and `border:solid` draws a border outside of everything including the `<legend>`.  I've tested in both Firefox and Chrome and no difference.  What am I missing?  Here is an example of my code.  I'm playing with different layouts so ignore the inconsistency.

```html
<div class=" col-4 col-sm-4 col-med-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 e-primary" style="justify-content:space-around">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Project Basics</legend>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <label for="txtName">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtName" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="txtDescription">Description</label>
        <textarea rows=3 cols=20 id="txtDescription"></textarea>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </fieldset>
</div>
<div class=" col-4 col-sm-4 col-med-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 e-primary" style="justify-content:space-around">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Cost Estimations</legend>
    <label for="txtEstTotalHrs">Estimated Total Hours</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtEstTotalHrs" />
    <label for="txtEstLaborCost">Estimated Labor Costs</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtEstLaborCosts" />
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

And this is what I'm seeing, no borders.
[image]

Update to comments:

- Mushroomator, yes I am using bootstrap.  Are you saying to add the whole bootstrap css to the snippet?  And I am the designer of the project.
- Mike K., Agreed, I am not seeing whats in the plain snippet so something is being overwritten.  I wasn't very clear but I did look at the what styles are being applied and at the Fieldset level, if I change the Border setting to 1px it draws an outside box around the fieldset.  I added an image from the dev tools.

*JonoJames, I tried adding styling to the tag like this `<fieldset style="border-color:black !important; border-style:solid !important">` and I still see nothing.  When I look at the dev tools, it shows those attributes set at the Element level but nothing changes on the front end.

This should be a simple problem.

**Testing Update**: I found the references to the bootstrap css in the _Layout.cshtml file so I started commenting them out , one at a time. The offender seems to be `<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />` The only reference to fieldset, other than fieldset:disabled, is in this line.

```
fieldset{min-width:0;padding:10rem;margin:10rem;border:10rem}legend{float:left;width:100%;padding:0;margin-bottom:.5rem;font-size:calc(1.275rem + .3vw);line-height:inherit}@media (min-width:1200px){legend{font-size:1.5rem}}legend+*{clear:left}
```

I've tried setting all properties to something other than zero but no effect.  settings like "10px" or "25rem".  Anytime I do get a border, its always an "outside" border like this:
[image]

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap? Or which CSS library are you using in which version? You could add that to the snippet, so the snippet would actually reflect what you see. Without the styling it certainly works as the snippet shows.

Comment: Could well be that the designers of that project don't want to have borders as spacing/ proximity is usually preferred over borders from an user experience point of view.

Comment: Running your snippet here works just fine, so: debug 101 time. Fire up your dev tools, click on a(ny) fieldset in the "inspector"/"elements" tab, and then look at which rules _remove_ the border in the CSS details panels. You already have to power to figure this one out all on your own simply by looking at which rules are getting applied, from which files, overriding which other rules, from which other files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out.  According to this discussion [Fieldset legend does not work](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/32548) everything is turned off for fieldset borders in Bootstrap 5. To get the original alignment of the Legend (inline with the border) you have to set the Legend `float:none;` and `width:auto;`

My final CSS looks like this:

```
fieldset {
    margin-bottom: 1em !important;
    border: 1px solid #666 !important;
    padding:1px !important;
}

legend {
    padding: 1px 10px !important;
    float:none;
    width:auto;
}
```

Thanks for all your input.  Reading through your replies a couple times helped me with my troubleshooting.

Comment: Please accept your answer in order to close the question.

Answer (score 1):

This should work!

```
<fieldset class="border rounded-3 p-3">
   <legend class="float-none w-auto px-3">
      Your Title
   </legend>
   <p>Your content</p>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a custom border with CSS

```css
.fieldsetColored{
  border-color: #F00;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="fieldsetColored">
  <legend>box</legend>
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
     <label for="txtEstTotalHrs">Estimated Total Hours</label></br>
     <input type="text" id="txtEstTotalHrs" /></br>
     <label for="txtEstLaborCost">Estimated Labor Costs</label></br>
     <input type="text" id="txtEstLaborCosts" /></br>
    </tr>
  </table>
</fieldset>
```

You probably have a conflicting style sheet somewhere that turns the border off If its bootstrap use the !important CSS override style attribute

[!important](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#important-rules)

looking at the  class list `<div class=" col-4 col-sm-4 col-med-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 e-primary" style="justify-content:space-around">`

This looks like bootstrap